# Subclass final method not being called

Tags: java, oop, methods, abstract, final

I don't get what's going on here, but the final method

```
s.castable()
```

that overrides the motherclass's namesake abstract method doesn't get called.

Here is where I try to call s.castable():

```
public void cast(String[] request) {
    System.out.println("cast called");
    if (this.session.getPlayer()==this.game.getTurnPlayer()) {
        System.out.println("first condition passed");
        Spell s = this.session.getPlayer().getCharacter().getSpells().get(Integer.valueOf(request[1]));
        ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Now printing spell: "+s);

        for (int i = 6; i < request.length; i++) {
            usernames.add(request[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("username create.d");
        if (s.castable()) {                                   //HERE
            System.out.println("Second condition passed");
            s.cast(Integer.valueOf(request[1]), Integer.valueOf(request[2]),request[3].charAt(0), request[4].charAt(0), usernames);
            String str = "";
            for (String st : usernames) {
                str += st;
            }
            this.session.send("YOUSPELL "+request[1]+" "+request[2]+" "+request[3]+" "+request[4]+" "+str);
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the "Spell" MotherClass:

```
public abstract class Spell {

private int manaCost;
private int coolDown;
private int range;
private Player player;

public abstract void cast(int x, int y, char mode1, char mode2,ArrayList<String> usernames);
public abstract Boolean castable();

//Then all getters and setters.
}
```

And here is the final class "Velocity":

```
public final class Velocity extends Spell {

private final int manaCost;
private final Player player;
private final int coolDown;
private final int coolDownTime;
private final int additionalMovement;
private final int spellRef;
private final ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList();

public Velocity(Player p) {
    this.spellRef = 0;
    this.additionalMovement = 5;
    this.player = p;
    this.manaCost = 5;
    this.coolDownTime = 3;
    this.coolDown = 0;
    super.setCoolDown(coolDown);
    super.setManaCost(manaCost);
    super.setPlayer(p);
}

@Override
public final void cast(int x, int y, char mode1, char mode2,ArrayList<String> usernames) {
    System.out.println("Velocity casted.");
    player.setMovement(player.getMovement() + additionalMovement);
    setCoolDown(coolDownTime);
}

@Override
public final Boolean castable() {
    System.out.println(player.getMana());
    System.out.println(manaCost);
    System.out.println(getCoolDown());
    if (player.getMana() >= manaCost && getCoolDown() >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Finally, the console output:

> `cast called
>   first condition passed
>   Now printing spell: model.haraka.be.Velocity@739bb60f
>   username create.d`.

As you can see the spell object is known.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem at hand here. if you're referring to the output `model.haraka.be.Velocity@739bb60f` then you'll need to override `toString()` , otherwise please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Too much code :(  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Aominè No, the System.out.println(s) call is only to get sure that the s object is instanceof Velocity. What I try and can't do is to call the "s.castable()" method

Comment: Your `s.castable()` simply returns `false`. Try to debug it and see what causes that.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible problem here can be that Abstract class Spell's variable `s` doesn't contain the reference to `Velocity` object.

hence the castable method of velocity class never gets called.

> If the `castable method` is returning false as mentioned by many
>   people `System.out.println()` statements must be printed which is not
>   the case I think.

But to be sure this is the problem, Please explain:

```
Spell s = this.session.getPlayer().getCharacter().getSpells().get(Integer.valueOf(request[1]));
```

What are below methods return type ?

- getPlayer()
- getSpells()
- get(Integer.valueOf(request[1])

This is too much to ask/comment in comment section hence posting as an answer.

Comment: My bad, the s.castable() is being called but the player.getMana(), manaCost, and getCoolDown() doesn't seem to return nothing. I will post my solution when I will be sure